# Supertype table with disjoint subtypes in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database-design, foreign-key, subtypes, enum

I want to have base parent table with few disjoint subtypes. To illustrate what I mean:

```
CREATE TABLE issues (
  issue_id SERIAL PRIMARY_KEY,
  issue_type CHAR(1) CHECK (issue_type IN ('B', 'F')),
  UNIQUE KEY (issue_id, issue_type)
);

CREATE TABLE bugs (
  issue_id INT PRIMARY_KEY,
  issue_type CHAR(1) CHECK (issue_type = 'B'),
  ...,
  FOREIGN KEY (issue_id, issue_type) REFERENCES issues(issue_id, issue_type)
);

CREATE TABLE features (
  issue_id INT PRIMARY_KEY,
  issue_type CHAR(1) CHECK (issue_type = 'F'),
  ...,
  FOREIGN KEY (issue_id, issue_type) REFERENCES issues(issue_id, issue_type)
);
```

To achieve this in MySQL, I tried to use ENUMs instead of unsupported CHECKs:

```
CREATE TABLE issues (
  issue_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  issue_type ENUM('B', 'F') NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE (issue_id, issue_type)
);

CREATE TABLE bugs (
  issue_id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  issue_type ENUM('B') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'B',
  text TEXT,
  FOREIGN KEY (issue_id, issue_type) REFERENCES issues(issue_id, issue_type)
);

CREATE TABLE features (
  issue_id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  issue_type ENUM('F') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'F',
  text TEXT,
  FOREIGN KEY (issue_id, issue_type) REFERENCES issues(issue_id, issue_type)
);
```

The issue is with the `features` table where I'm not able to insert any row, because of `ERROR (1452): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails ...`

```
-- OK
INSERT INTO issues (issue_id, issue_type) VALUES (1, 'B');
INSERT INTO issues (issue_id, issue_type) VALUES (2, 'F');
INSERT INTO bugs(issue_id, issue_type, text) VALUES (1, 'B', 'bar');
-- ERROR (1452): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`...`.`features`, CONSTRAINT `features_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`issue_id`, `issue_type`) REFERENCES `issues` (`issue_id`, `issue_type`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)
INSERT INTO features(issue_id, issue_type, text) VALUES (2, 'F', 'baz');
```

I guess this is caused by the incompatible ENUM definitions in `issues` and `features` table.

My question is what do you see as best alternative to do this?

I can think of these options:

1. create `issue_types` table and reference it from all tables; in `bugs` and `features` check allowed values in trigger
2. instead of ENUMs use BIT(1) and check allowed values in trigger (without the list in separate table)

Comment: I think it all ends up the same way: you do your CHECKs via triggers (as in [CHECK constraint in MySQL is not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2115497/check-constraint-in-mysql-is-not-working))

Comment: Enums don't work like you want them to. See [this stackoverflow answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17407959/562459) for an alternative.